# How to assign LabelEncoder to variable using loop in python

Tags: python, loops, variables

I'm trying to use the following code to assign LabelEncoder function to variables but it doesn't seem to do the job.

```
labelencoder_first_browser=1    #Using this line as QA to see if the the value changes after the loop
cols = [labelencoder_gender ,labelencoder_signup_method,labelencoder_signup_language,
    labelencoder_signup_affiliate_channel,labelencoder_signup_affiliate_provider,
    labelencoder_first_affiliate_tracked,labelencoder_signup_app,
    labelencoder_first_device_type,labelencoder_first_browser]

for i in cols:
cols = LabelEncoder()
labelencoder_first_browser
```

I get

```
1
```

instead of

```
labelencoder_first_browser
Out[28]: LabelEncoder()
```

Comment: why you use the same name `cols` for list and for `LabelEncoder()`. You get element `i` from list but you never use it. You create `LabelEncoder()` which doesn't know anything about `labelencoder_first_browser` because you never use `labelencoder_first_browser`

Comment: read [documentation for LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You create `LabelEncoder` but you assing to `cols`, not `labelencoder_first_browser`. And you not use column with data in this encoder.

---

In example I use list with column's names. In for-loop I create LabelEncoder, keep it in dictionary using colum name, and at once I use it with data from this column and create new column with encoded data. Later I can use encoders from dictionary to encode results back to original values.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'first_browser': ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Opera'],
        'gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
     })

all_labelencoders = {}

cols = ['first_browser', 'gender'] # strings with names

for name in cols:
    labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
    all_labelencoders[name] = labelencoder

    labelencoder.fit( df[name] )
    df['labelencoder_' + name] = labelencoder.transform( df[name] )


print(all_labelencoders['first_browser'])
print(all_labelencoders['gender'])

#for name in cols:
#    print(name, all_labelencoders[name])

print(df)

# inverse data

for name in cols:
    encoder = all_labelencoders[name]
    data = encoder.inverse_transform(df['labelencoder_' + name])
    print(data)
```